# Show that two logical expressions are equivalent without using the truth table.

Tags: logic

I would like to show that the expression (S => P) AND (NOT S => Q) and the expression (S AND P) OR (NOT S AND Q) are equivalent.

I am not interested in any solution using truth tables or exhaustive trying of truth assignments, I find these approaches rather unilluminating.

Comment: What's the box?

Comment: What box? Do you mean any character I used?

Comment: @Adam I see two squares: between `S` and `P`, and between `S` and `Q` in your first expression.

Comment: should be ok now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following facts will get you most of the way there: $$A\Rightarrow B\equiv(\neg A)\vee B$$ $$A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv(A\wedge B)\vee(A\wedge C)$$ $$A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv(A\vee B)\wedge(A\vee C)$$

Comment: Maybe $A \lor (A \land B) = A$ as well?

Comment: Is it true that (¬S ∨ P) ∧ S = (S ∧ P) ?

Comment: @Adam: Yes, it is, since $$\begin{align}(\neg S\vee P)\wedge S &= (\neg S\wedge S)\vee(P\wedge S)\\ &= P\wedge S\\ &= S\wedge P.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
(S \to P) \land (\lnot S \to Q) &=& (\lnot S \lor P) \land (S \lor Q) \\
&=& (\lnot S \land S) \lor (\lnot S \land Q) \lor (P \land S) \lor (P \land Q) \\
&=& (\lnot S \land Q) \lor (P \land S)\lor (P \land Q) \\
&=&(\lnot S \land Q) \lor (P \land S)\lor ((P \land Q)\land (\lnot S \lor S)) \\
&=&(\lnot S \land Q) \lor (P \land S)\lor (P \land Q \land \lnot S) \lor  (P \land Q \land  S)\\
&=&(\lnot S \land Q) \lor (P \land S)
\end{eqnarray}
Line 2: Distributed property.

Line 3: Law of noncontradiction.

Line 4: Law of excluded middle.

Line 5: Distributed property.

Line 6: Monotonicity of entailment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint on how to get started: You are considering the statements
$$
(\neg S \lor P)\land (S\lor Q)
$$
By distributive laws you get
$$
(\neg S \land S)\lor(P\land S)\lor (\neg S\land Q)\lor (P\land Q)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using (informal) natural deduction rather than algebraic-type laws.

Assume $(S \implies P) \wedge (\neg S \implies Q)$. Deduce $S \implies P$.  Deduce $\neg S \implies Q$.  Using the law of excluded middle, deduce $S \vee \neg S$.

- Case 1: Assume $S$. Deduce $P$ by Modus Ponens.  Deduce $S \wedge P$.
- Case 2: Assume $\neg S$.  Deduce $Q$ by Modus Ponens.  Deduce $\neg S \wedge Q$.

Deduce $(S \wedge P) \vee (\neg S \wedge Q)$.

Conversely, assume $(S \wedge P) \vee (\neg S \wedge Q)$.

- Case 1: Assume $S \wedge P$.  Deduce $S$.  Deduce $P$.  Deduce $S \implies P$ (because the consequent is true.)  Deduce $\neg S \implies Q$ (because the antecedant is false.)  Deduce $(S \implies P) \wedge (\neg S \implies Q)$.
- Case 2: Assume $(\neg S \wedge Q)$. Deduce $\neg S$.  Deduce $Q$. Deduce $S \implies P$ (because the antecedant is false.)  Deduce $\neg S \implies Q$ (because the consequent is true.)  Deduce $(S \implies P) \wedge (\neg S \implies Q)$.

Comment: I like your argument, I was thinking along similar lines and that's how I decided that these two expressions are equivalent. (But I wanted other ways of seeing that and that's why I posted here.)

Comment: @Adam  Ah, I see. I just didn't want the other answers to give the impression that Hilbert-style systems were the only way to do it.